# Removing the :active pseudo-class from an element

Tags: javascript, pseudo-class

I'd like to be able to tell an element that it is no longer `:active` so that the CSS rules no longer apply. Is there any way to do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 11):

Possible solutions :

**1) Using classes :**

JS :

```
document.getElementById("element").classList.remove("hasactive");
```

CSS :

```
#element.hasactive:active {
    background:blue;
}
```

**2) Preventing default mousedown functionality (active state) :**

**EDIT :** Apparently, this only works on Firefox.

JS :

```
document.getElementById("element").onmousedown = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

**3) Removing a style element with the css rule in it**

HTML :

```
<style id="activestyle">
#element:active {
/*Your code here*/
}
</style>
```

JS :

```
document.getElementById("activestyle").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick by resetting the DOM element.

```
function resetElement(e){
    var $e = $(e);
    var $original = $e.clone();
    $e.replaceWith($original);
}
```

Then call it with:

```
resetElement(document.activeElement);
```

Comment: Tested working. 
This seems to be the best answer to brute force the removal of the :active using just JS.

Comment: Just note that if the element had any events attached (like onclick), it will lost them and you need to reattach them after cloning.

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery users:
JS:

```
$(".btn").click( function () { $(this).blur(); } );
```

HTML:

```
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-success">press me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement):

```
document.activeElement = null;
```

OR

```
document.activeElement && document.activeElement.blur();
```

Comment: This is to detect the :focus state, not the :active state

Comment: `document.activeElement` is [read-only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement). So assigning null to it will have no effect.